# Attributes not being assigned to a class? Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

Working on a text game, I ran into this error where `playercharacter` isn't assigning any of the variables I've given it. An example run is as follows:

```
What is your name?
Ty

playercharacter.getname()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
playercharacter.getname()

AttributeError: 'player' object has no attribute 'getname'
```

No matter which attribute I try to call, it returns the same error message.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here's the full code below:

```
class player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, level, ST, PE, EN, CH, IN, AG, LK, location, HP, XP, NXTLVL):
        self.name = name
        self.level = level
        self.ST = ST
        self.PE = PE
        self.EN = EN
        self.CH = CH
        self.IN = IN
        self.AG = AG
        self.LK = LK
        self.smallguns = 2 * AG + LK
        self.bigguns = 2 * ST + LK
        self.unarmed = 2 * EN + LK
        self.meleeweapons = 2 * ST + LK
        self.throwing = 2 * AG + LK
        self.firstaid = 2 * IN + LK
        self.sneak = 2 * AG + LK
        self.lockpick = 2 * PE + LK
        self.steal = 2 * AG + LK
        self.science = 2 * IN + LK
        self.repair = 2 * IN + LK
        self.speech = 2 * CH + LK
        self.location = location
        self.HP = HP
        self.XP = XP
        self.NXTLVL = NXTLVL

        def getname(self):
            return self.name
        def getlevel(self):
            return self.level
        def getST(self):
            return self.ST
        def getPE(self):
            return self.PE
        def getEN(self):
            return self.EN
        def getCH(self):
            return self.CH
        def getIN(self):
            return self.IN
        def getAG(self):
            return self.AG
        def getLK(self):
            return self.LK
        def getsmallguns(self):
            return self.smallguns
        def getbigguns(self):
            return self.bigguns
        def getunarmed(self):
            return self.unarmed
        def getmeleeweapons(self):
            return self.meleeweapons
        def getthrowing(self):
            return self.throwing
        def getfirstaid(self):
            return self.firstaid
        def getsneak(self):
            return self.sneak
        def getlockpick(self):
            return self.lockpick
        def getsteal(self):
            return self.steal
        def getscience(self):
            return self.science
        def getrepair(self):
            return self.repair
        def getspeech(self):
            return self.speech
        def getlocation(self):
            return self.location
        def getHP(self):
            return self.HP
        def getXP(self):
            return self.XP
        def getNXTLVL(self):
            return self.NXTLVL
        def __str__(self):
            print"""
Name: %s

Level:   %s
XP:      %s
Nxt Lvl: %s

Location: %s

HP: %s

ST: %s
PE: %s
EN: %s
CH: %s
IN: %s
AG: %s
LK: %s

Small Guns:    %s
Big Guns:      %s
Unarmed:       %s
Melee Weapons: %s
Throwing:      %s
First-Aid:     %s
Sneak:         %s
Lockpick:      %s
Steal:         %s
Science:       %s
Repair:        %s
Speech:        %s
""" %(self.getname(), self.getlevel(), self.getXP(), self.getNXTLVL(), self.getlocation(), self.getHP(), self.getST(), self.getPE(), self.getEN(), self.getCH(), self.getIN(), self.getAG(), self.getLK(), self.getsmallguns(), self.getbigguns(), self.getunarmed(), self.getmeleeweapons(), self.getthrowing(), self.getfirstaid(), self.getsneak(), self.getlockpick(), self.getsteal(), self.getscience(), self.getrepair(), self.getspeech())

player_location = {'player_grid_height': 1, 'player_grid_length': 1}

playercharacter = player(raw_input("""What is your name?
"""), 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, player_location, 1, 0, 50)

playercharacter.__str__()
```

Also, any general advice would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overindented your other methods; all the `def get*` names should be at the same indentation level as `def __init__`, not the level of `__init__`'s contents.

As far as general advice goes: Don't write Java-style accessors. The Pythonic approach is to just access the attributes directly, or if you insist on some protection, naming the instance attributes with a leading underscore, and using `@property` accessors. So if `name` should be protected against mutation, you'd have:

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    self._name = ...

@property
def name(self):
    return self._name
```

so use of the property remains `myobj.name`, with no need to explicitly call a function or use superfluous `get` prefixes.

Comment: @TyCompton You know, you can accept ShadowRanger's answer if you want